# Simplifying a function handle using another function handle with partially given variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

With the following code in Matlab"

```
f = @(a,x) a*x+3;
g = @(x) f(4,x)
```

I get g as a function handle of the function handle f.

```
g = @(x)f(4,x)
```

However, I want to get g as a function handle without being expressed by another function handle, i.e., `g = @(x)4*x+3`. How can I get the simplified function handle?

Comment: I don't know an easy way to do that. You are defining `g` in terms of `f`, and that's what you get. In case it helps, note that `g` includes all the information necessary about `f`. To see it: `info = functions(g); disp(info), disp(info.workspace{1})`

Comment: According to [this post in Matlab Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/277444-efficiently-combine-anonymous-functions#answer_216680), try `syms x; 
g2 = matlabFunction( simplify(g(x)), 'vars', x);`

Comment: You are confusing anonymous functions with symbolic math. An anonymous function is just code. It’s a “function” in the computer science sense, not in the mathematics sense. MATLAB will not rewrite your code for you, the code is as you write it.

Comment: By the way, I refer to “anonymous function” above because that is what you are talking about. It’s a function without a name, you can only refer to it because you have its “handle”, which is MATLAB speak for a reference to a function.